# Chrome mv3 await sendMessage to background service worker

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

It appears the response is sent immediately (it logs in the console immediately). Is there a problem with the code or some other issue?

**popup.js** (browser action)

```js
async function send() {
  const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({...});
  console.log('response called', response);
}
```

**background.js** (service worker)

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(e => onMessage(e));

async function onMessage(message) {
  return fetch('https://example.com/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    console.log('json called', response);
    return response;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error called', error);
  });
}
```

Result

```
response called undefined
json called {...}
```

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. It answers the question that it is a bug. Sadly, the callback solution doesn't suit my situation (cross -browser compatible code).

Comment: Firefox supports callback-based sendResponse. Which browser doesn't?

Comment: @wOxxOm Firefox `chrome` namespace API in MV3 will be promise based. It is callback-based in MV2.

Comment: The general architecture is a different matter. The point I make is that sendResponse will work in Firefox.